# Getting an element from a matrix in Haskell

Tags: haskell

If i want to get a specific element from a matrix, how would i do that ?

For example:

```
getCell :: [[Int]] -> Int -> Int -> Int
```

with the input:

```
getCell [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5]] 1 2
```

should return the value 4 (indexes start from zero).

I'm familiarized with the !! operator, but here it is a different scenario.

Any help?

Comment: You need to apply the `(!!)` operator twice, since you have a list of lists: `getCell nss row col = nss !! row !! col`.

Comment: While not directly relevant to your question, be aware that defining a matrix as a list of lists of elements is silly for anyting other than pedagogical reasons or algorithms that consume the entire matrix from start to finish (row-wise). Haskell lists are linked lists that index in O(n) time. For constant-time indexing, build your matrix using [`Vector`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector)s instead.

Comment: Elaborating on the @gspr comment: using `(!!)` to access list elements is arguably the worst method. Typically you `map,filter,zip,fold` to scan a list, or just use recursion.